# Apache Axis2/C Installation

Tags: axis2c

i have tried installing Apache Axis2/C on Linux but no success.. with libxml2

Here are my efforts
    1) libxml2 was installed successfully
    Flags : LIBXML2_CFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include/libxml2
    LIBXML2_LIBS='-L/usr/local/lib/hpux32 -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -liconv -lm'
    AXIS2C_HOME = /tmp
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH = {$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:$AXIS2C_HOME/lib

```
Ran --prefix=${AXIS2C_HOME} --enable-libxml2=yes
Installation fails with following error:

checking whether to build libxml2 xml parser library... checking pkg-config is at least        version 0.9.0... ./configure[21268]: /local/lib/hpux32.
no
yes
checking for LIBXML2... configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it
is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full
path to pkg-config.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBXML2_CFLAGS
and LIBXML2_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

i do not hold pkg-config utility but i have set  LIBXML2_CFLAGS and LIBXML2_LIBS, configuration file does not have any information.

can someone please assist here?

Thanks,
Hilesh